# add event to Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery plugin and I want to add some event to it.
Any help, tips, or tutorial?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319264/jquery-plugin-handling-events

Comment: Uhm, what plugin? We can't answer something if we don't know what it's about…

Comment: @Anriëtte Combrink : its some popup plugin and i want do something after that is closed. [Link](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As I understand correctly If you have some kind of button that close the popup and you need a function that is triggered after close.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.somePlugin = function(options) {
    // do some stuff with popup
    $('#closeButton').click(function(e) {
      //close popup
      if (options.onAfterClose !== undefined) {
         options.onAfterClose(e);
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

it just pass the event from click event.

```
$('#someId').somePlugin({
    onAfterClose: function(e) {
        alert('after close');
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a similar plugin structure except that I'm setting up 'e' to have have certain values which should be passed along as parameters, but it always comes out as null. So no parameters! Any ideas?

Comment: managed to get sorted. It has to do with using .call in Javascript where the first parameter passed should be 'this' as in onChange.call(this,thenParameters)

Comment: Just what I was looking for and well done for understanding the question!

Comment: options should also be checked for undefined

Answer (score 16):

In your jquery plugin, the first thing you will have to do is trigger your custom event somewhere in your plugin code:

> $("#someElement").trigger("someSpecialEvent");

You can also pass data inside of your trigger function if you want.

```
$("#someElement").trigger("someSpecialEvent", "this does not need to be a string");
```

Next, create an event handler somewhere else in your plugin code for your custom event:

```
$("#someElement").bind("someSpecialEvent", function(event, data) {
    //If you had passed anything in your trigger function, you can grab it using the second parameter in the callback function.
});
```

You can then allow a user to pass a callback function as an option like this:

```
$("#sampleElement").myPlugin({ 
    someEvent: function() {
        //user logic
    }
});
```

Finally, inside of your plugin code, you can call the user's function a few different ways.  An example would be:

```
$.fn.samplePlugin = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.samplePlugin.options, options);
        $("sampleElement").bind("specialEvent", function() {
             options.someEvent.call();
        });
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery docs has everything about triggering an event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Any element that has been attached to an event using `$.bind()` will be notified that the event had been triggered and execute its code.

Example:

```
$(document).trigger('my.event');
```

jQuery supports 'namespaced' events, so you can name the event something like `mypluginName.eventName` to make sure no other plugin interferes with you events ;)

Simple and clean, although be careful, docs state that:

> Although .trigger() simulates an event
>   activation, complete with a
>   synthesized event object, it does not
>   perfectly replicate a
>   naturally-occurring event.

Nice day

Answer (score 0):

$("#someElement").on("someSpecialEvent", function(event) {

});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).